# How to apply CSS style based on parent element, similar to media queries

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page to test responsive layout of a page in my application, however media queries only work with window resolution, is there any way to apply CSS while changing the width of parent  element.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .child-element{font-size: 30px};

    @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
        .child-element{font-size: 24px}
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent-element">
    <div class="child-element">Heading 1</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to child-element style based on the width of parent-element, if the parent-element width is less than or equal to 768px then similar style I have written in media query should apply.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail to your question? Can you explain a scenario (using some code) in which new CSS should apply when the parent element's width changes?

Comment: Thank you @dchang for sharing the similar question.